# Getting the date in Haskell in the local timezone

Tags: date, haskell, time, timezone

I am currently using the code below in a project
`date :: IO (Integer,Int,Int) -- :: (year,month,day)`
`date = getCurrentTime >>= return . toGregorian . utctDay`
However it does not give the correct local date when run. I have run this at 1am on the 26/04/11 yet the function results in `(2011, 4, 25)`. 
 I understand that the `utctDay` refers to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and therefore isn't the local system date, but is it possible to get the same format of date as seen above but with the correct date depending on the machines system date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try getZonedTime: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.2.0.4/doc/html/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#v:getZonedTime

Comment: This gives the correct time but not in a great format. Is there a way to get it in the format described previously? `date = getZonedTime >>= return . **something** . **something**` maybe

Comment: `fmap (toGregorian . localDay  . zonedTimeToLocalTime) getZonedTime` -- untested. The haskell date/time libraries are powerful, but the api is a bit of a maze to navigate.

Comment: great stuff! Thank you. Date and Time libraries are moderatly overwhelming to haskell newbies such as myself!